# what's wrong with settimer when passing a small number of elapsed milliseconds?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am trying to simulate a falling iron ball taking in count gravity, so I am using visual C++ Win32.

It works ok so the ball falls as I expected but if I set the `UINT uElapse` to small value like `5` Milliseconds the windows draws correctly until a couple a minutes then I get a blank window!

I re-checked resource memory leak whenever I create an object but when it gets blank no message reporting "running out of resources".

```
SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, 100, NULL); // works fine
SetTimer(hWnd, ID_TIMER, 5, NULL);   // produces a blank windows after a few minutes!
```

Comment: Maybe five milliseconds is *to short* and you don't have time to do what you do when the timer elapses before the next time elapses, and suddenly you have maybe hundreds or thousands of timer event queued?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: thank you at first. I have only two timers: one for drawing (animation) I set it too short to get an animation near to the real. the second is for elapsed seconds to calculate velocity.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: I think you are really correct. So is there some work around? another alternative..?

Comment: Do you *really* need 200 FPS for the animation? Depending on what you are animating, anything from 10 to 60 FPS might be enough.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: ok I'll try it. thanks

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: even 15 milliseconds causes the same problem!

Comment: Read about timer resolution. Typically doesn't get down to 15ms. Using a timer to measure elapsed time doesn't work. Timer messages are synthesised when the queue is empty. They are not reliable in the way you think they are. You will need to redesign this part of your program.

Comment: If this is for animation, make sure to base it off of the *real* elapsed time. Timers are inherently inaccurate. Using the elapsed time in your animation code makes sure that this isn't an issue.

Comment: @IInspectable: yes I use a double-buffering technique so drawing then clear then drawing with new coordinates. you mean I should implement my own?

Comment: A "blank window" is usually the result of the painting code failing to create a brush or pen.  Leaking GDI objects and not testing the return value of GDI functions like CreatePen() are *very* common bugs.  Otherwise easy to diagnose with Task Manager, Processes Tab.  Add the GDI Objects column.  The show is over when it reaches 10000.

Comment: Double-buffering is fine, but it isn't sufficient. Your rendering code must take the **elapsed** time into account, and not just assume that each step is rendered at a fixed interval. Your code probably has something like `y -= 10;` to calculate the new coordinate. That should be `y = y0 - velocity * elapsedTime;` instead.

Comment: @IInspectable: even I only draw the ball without moving it the window gets blank after a while thus @Some programmer dude is right however I still search for a good way. by the way is there any alternatives let's say `wxWidgets`?

Comment: You have two issues: Relying on an accurate timer and a resource leak. I commented on the former, while Hans Passant [explained](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41958798/whats-wrong-with-settimer-when-passing-a-small-number-of-elapsed-milliseconds?noredirect=1#comment71097809_41958798) how to analyze the latter. Without seeing any code, there's nothing more we can do to help.

Comment: You may be experiencing the [Microsoft Minute](http://www.userfriendly.org/cartoons/archives/99mar/19990318.html).